# Finding a square root through iteration in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, square-root

I have a homework assignment due and I am having trouble with my loops. I first have to find the next highest and lowest square roots through loops which I already can do. Next my assignment tells me that I need to get an approximation of the square root which I do by averaging the next highest and lowest square roots of the integer. Then I must ask the user for the number of decimal places of accuracy they want. Here is a quote from the assignment:

> A count-controlled loop should then be constructed; it will execute once for each of the desired decimal positions; in the example, this loop will execute four times (once each for the tenths, hundredths, thousandths, and ten-thousandths decimal positions). Use a counter such as decimalPosition to keep track of which pass the loop is on.

This is where I have trouble, I am using a while loop based on the number of decimal positions the user has entered but my loop doesn't complete the loop. I am new to programming so please forgive me if this is a truly simple. Here is my while code:

```
for (int decimalPosition = 1; decimalPosition <= decimal; decimalPosition++)
{
    while (baseRoot*baseRoot > num)
    {
        baseRoot = baseRoot - (pow((.1),decimalPosition));
        cout << fixed << setprecision(decimal) << baseRoot << endl;
    }

}
```

here is my output so far

```
Enter a number you wish to know the square root of: 8
Enter the number of decimal places of accuracy you want: 7
Find the square root of 8 to 7 decimal places: 
2.6000000
2.7000000
2.8000000
2.9000000
2.9000000 square root of 8.0000000
```

Comment: Can you remove the homework tag - it is deprecated

Comment: @AdrianCornish think its gone now, I can't see it now anyway :)

Comment: You realize, of course, that what you have "so far" is utterly incorrect.  That's not the square root of 8 to 7 decimal places.

Comment: I did realize this and it was why I had posed this question earlier but I have since found my problem which was an malfunctioning count controlled loop. Thanks to everyone who tried to help me!

Answer (score 4):

It's called [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), and its convergence is quadratic.  That should help you figure it out.

PS - The Babylonians discovered it first, but Newton gets credit for it.

Comment: Don't get me started on the Babylonians.

Comment: I got the math right on it. I found that I have incorrectly implemented my loops. my count controled loop was not initialized properly. Now my code magically finds square roots through this method. It is quite beautiful!!

Answer (score 0):

To make your loop works, you can add a statement

```
baseRoot = baseRoot + (pow((.1),decimalPosition));
```

after the while loop because your need to make sure `baseRoot` is bigger than the answer before each iteration. Like this:

```
for (int decimalPosition = 1; decimalPosition <= decimal; decimalPosition++)
{
    while (baseRoot*baseRoot > num)
    {
        baseRoot = baseRoot - (pow((.1),decimalPosition));
        cout << fixed << setprecision(decimal) << baseRoot << endl;
    }
    baseRoot = baseRoot + (pow((.1),decimalPosition));
}
```

Now you can get the answer `2.8284271`.

By the way, there's another efficient way called **bisection method** (similar to binary search) to solve this kind of problem (related to **Monotonic function**) without too much math:

```
double mySqrt(double x, double epsilon) {
    double left = 0, right = x;
    while (right - left > epsilon) {
        double mid = (left + right) / 2;
        if (mid * mid > x) {
            right = mid;
        } else {
            left = mid;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

It's simple, stupid :)